# Mechanize extract images from HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, nokogiri, mechanize

How can I extract an specific image's src parameter from the current page using Mechanize or Nokogiri?

The image is inside something similar to this:

```
<div class="aaa">
    <div id="bbb">
        <div class="pp">
        <img src="/user/photo/photo01" alt="photo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is what I was trying:**

```
agent = ::Mechanize.new
agent.get ("some html url page")
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(agent.page.uri.to_s))
@result = doc.css('img')
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's expected you'll show a minimal example of what you tried. As is it looks like you want us to write code for you which isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Its been a long time, but its never too late to make the things right. So, since I decided to be active in this community, I started by changing what I did wrong in past. I apologize my behaviour, you were right, it wasn't the best, I have changed the post with an example on what I was trying. Thanks.

Comment: No need to apologize, at least for what I see. SO's goal is to create a site that's akin to Wikipedia or an online cookbook, only for programming problems and the accepted best solutions to the problem, a reference book in other words. It's a community effort, and even those asking questions have responsibilities to work toward those goals. Adding the code and letting is know what's been done helps us answer by ruling out any number of other possible scenarios and helps us help you by getting answers more quickly and better tuned to the situation. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

The following will print the `src` attribute for every `a` tag within `.aaa` and `#bbb` divs:

```
html = %Q{
  <div class="aaa">
    <div id="bbb">
      <div class="pp">
        <img src="/user/photo/photo01" alt="photo">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
}

doc = Nokogiri(html)
doc.search('.aaa #bbb img').each |link| 
  puts link.attr('src')
end
```